# How exactly can quantum interference inhibit the creation of spontaneous emission (via the purcell effect)?

Tags: photons, cavity-qed

What is the simplest model for understanding how spontaneously emitted radiation from an atom is inhibited by a cavity?

Considering an off-resonant cavity, it is said that there is some quantum interference that prevents the radiation from being created. But interference of what?

Here are my thoughts:
Understanding how mirrors can produce classical electric-field interference is simple. I believe that the math for this interference should resemble the interference of the wavefunction of a single photon emitted. But I've never seen this worked out explicitly.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Do you really mean "inhibited"? The Purcell effect is the opposite: an enhancement of the decay rate of an atom induced by stronger coupling to the cavity.

Comment: @Wolpertinger, thanks for the feedback. When on resonance you get enhancement, but when off-resonant you'll get the opposite effect.